# Setting attribute 'selected' to an option not working neither with jQuery nor with vanilla js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a select, the select accepts multiple options (2 max):

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="2">
  <option id="s1" value="Mustard Heinz">Mustard Heinz</option>
  <option id="s2" value="Ketchup Heinz">Ketchup Heinz</option>
  <option id="s3" value="Relish Whatever">Relish Whatever</option>
</select>
```

From my back-end, I receive a `String` like this:

`['Mustard Heinz', ' Ketchup Heinz']`

So what I want is that, when the page loads, `Mustard Heinz` and `Ketchup Heinz` will be selected.

What I've tried:

**vanilla js approach**:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var selected_sauces = "['Mustard Heinz', ' Ketchup Heinz']" //string from backend
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Mustard Heinz")){
        var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
        s1.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Ketchup Heinz")){
        var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
        s2.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Relish Whatever")){
        var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
        s3.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
});
```

**jQuery approach**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var selected_sauces = "['Mustard Heinz', ' Ketchup Heinz']" //string from backend
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Mustard Heinz")){
        $('#s1').prop({defaultSelected: true});
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Ketchup Heinz")){
        $('#s2').prop({defaultSelected: true});
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Relish Whatever")){
        $('#s3').prop({defaultSelected: true});
    }
});
```

Comment: Is there supposed to be an extra whitespace in ```" Ketchup Heinz"```?

Comment: Yeah, it might be a space or not, that is why I use `includes` instead of exact match

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `document.getElemendById()`, you need to put your id in some single or double quote like this `document.getElemendById('s1')`.

Here is an example:

```js
    var selected_sauces = "['Mustard Heinz', ' Ketchup Heinz']" //string from backend
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Mustard Heinz")){
        var s1 = document.getElementById('s1');
        s1.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Ketchup Heinz")){
        var s2 = document.getElementById('s2');
        s2.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Relish Whatever")){
        var s3 = document.getElementById('s3');
        s3.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>


<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="2">
  <option id="s1" value="Mustard Heinz">Mustard Heinz</option>
  <option id="s2" value="Ketchup Heinz">Ketchup Heinz</option>
  <option id="s3" value="Relish Whatever">Relish Whatever</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

The same approach as #Imperyum answer works for JQuery as well.

if you don't emit the

```
$(document).ready(function() {})
```

line it won't work.

```js
var selected_sauces = "['Mustard Heinz', ' Ketchup Heinz']"; //string from backend
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Mustard Heinz")){
        $('#s1').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Ketchup Heinz")){
        $('#s2').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
    if (selected_sauces.includes("Relish Whatever")){
        $('#s3').prop('selected', 'selected');
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.14.0-beta2/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>

<select class="selectpicker" multiple data-max-options="2">
  <option id="s1" value="Mustard Heinz">Mustard Heinz</option>
  <option id="s2" value="Ketchup Heinz">Ketchup Heinz</option>
  <option id="s3" value="Relish Whatever">Relish Whatever</option>
</select>
```